# Is dmPaperSize=DMPAPER_USER the same as dmPaperSize=0?

Tags: c++, winapi, printing

I saw this paragraph in the [DEVMODE docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which got me confused.

> dmPaperSize
>
> For printer devices only, selects the size of the paper to print on.
>   This member can be set to zero if the length and width of the paper
>   are both set by the dmPaperLength and dmPaperWidth members. Otherwise,
>   the dmPaperSize member can be set to a device specific value greater
>   than or equal to DMPAPER_USER or to one of the following predefined
>   values.

In it they say that dmPaperLength and dmPaperWidth are used only if dmPaperSize=0. The way they talk about it, it seems that dmPaperLength and dmPaperWidth should not be used with DMPAPER_USER.

That's what I find confusing. I thought DMPAPER_USER means using a custom page size. Is it different from specifying 0? How is the custom size specified if dmPaperLength and dmPaperWidth can't be used with DMPAPER_USER?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is a [Bug in the documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/108924).

According to [The folks over at codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=458617) you should use DMPAPER_USER instead of 0. There are a number of code samples in that discussion thread.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the documentation snippet you provided, DMPAPER_USER is described as "a device specific value". To me this means that the interpretation of that value is left to the printer driver itself, and the usage of dmPaperLength and dmPaperWidth would be up to the driver.

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense. So DMPAPER_USER is actually like WM_USER is for messages - it denotes a range that can be used for printer specific paper sizes. Thanks!

Comment: I just saw the second answer to this question. It seems that it's the right one.

Comment: According to the [same CodeGuru thread](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?458617-Change-paper-size&p=1749262#post1749262) post #11, I think Mark's answer is the correct one -- some drivers might use `DMPAPER_USER` and some use `291` (or `32767` in my case)